# Eclipse: knowing which Project Wizard was used

Tags: eclipse, project

I created a project but I don't remember which wizard I used. Running Eclipse Java EE, there's a huge number of them.

Is there a way to get that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: No!

The files related to the Eclipse project properties are the `.settings` folder and the `.project` file. None of those contain the information you seek.

You could try to guess it from the project properties but this bears some problems:

- You'd have to know which wizard creates which properties
- The association is not distinct
- The properties could have been changed by now

This makes such an approach unrealiable and practically unusable.